# Am I returning the correct value from my method & am I writing it correctly?

Tags: java, methods, return

I'll preface my question with the statement that I am very new to Java, so I apologise if my code is totally disgusting to read.

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm writing a program that takes two integers from the user, a low value and a high value, and sends both integers to two different methods. Method #1 has a simple for loop and should print out all of the numbers between the lowest number and the highest number that are multiples of 3 or 5, and Method #2 does the same except for numbers that are multiples of 3 or 5 it also checks if that number is also a multiple of 6 and, if so, it prints the number and an asterisk next to it.

**What I'm having trouble with:** I'm pretty stumped on what I need to return from my methods & how to return anything at all. This is the first time I've worked on a method properly (just moved up from "Hello World) and from what I can see I don't really need to return anything at all. All the code that I've put in my methods pretty much complete the program, so I thought maybe returning the integers I sent would be enough, apparently it's not. So, without further ado, here's my code.

**The Error:**

```
javac BonusQ.java
.\MethodOne.java:19: error: illegal start of type
                return(int lowestRange, int highestRange);
                ^
.\MethodTwo.java:36: error: illegal start of type
                return(int lowestRange, int highestRange);
                ^
```

**The Main:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BonusQ
{
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

                int lowestRange = 0;
                int highestRange = 0;

                System.out.println("Enter the lowest integer in your range");
                lowestRange = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter the highest integer in your range");
                highestRange = scan.nextInt();

                MethodOne.NoAsterisk(lowestRange, highestRange);
                MethodTwo.Asterisk(lowestRange, highestRange);

        }
}
```

**MethodOne:**

```
public class MethodOne
{
        public static int NoAsterisk(int lowestRange, int highestRange)
        {
                for(int i = lowestRange; i <= highestRange; i++)
                {
                        if (i%5 == 0)
                        {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        }
                        else if (i%3 == 0)
                        {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        }
                }

        }

        return(int lowestRange, int highestRange);

}
```

**MethodTwo:**

```
public class MethodTwo
{
        public static int Asterisk(int lowestRange, int highestRange)
        {
                for(int i = lowestRange; i <= highestRange; i++)
                {
                        if (i%5 == 0)
                        {
                                if (i%5 == 0 && i%6 == 0)
                                {
                                System.out.println(i + "*");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                System.out.println(i);
                                }
                        }
                        else if (i%3 == 0)
                        {
                                if (i%3 == 0 && i%6 == 0)
                                {
                                System.out.println(i + "*");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                System.out.println(i);
                                }
                        }


                }


        }

        return(int lowestRange, int highestRange);
}
```

Sorry if the post is a bit beefy to read, I just find that adding my thoughts on the code might help you explain to me what's going wrong, seeing as you may not know the extent of my incompetence :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return anything, being that the methods are printing out all the values.

You can change them into void methods, for example:

```
public static void asterisk(int lowest, int highest) {
    //loops and if statements

    //no return statement!
}
```

The code in the methods will run and voila, you are done!

EDIT: That being said, there's a lot more than can be done to make this code more Java-like, but for now this will work.

Comment: Thank you! It's like every time I ask a question on here it's one thing that I need to change ¬_¬, I'll probably have my questions restricted soon :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Classes have members.

Members are either some variables or arrays of variables
and the methods of a class.

So you got

```
public class MyMethod
{

   public static int Asterisk(int loRange, int hiRange)
      {
           // Do magic let's make a sum for this example

           // You enter loRange and hiRange (you defined it above)


            return loRange + hiRange // Here the method returns a result

      }
}

// So then....

public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            // WHATEVER IS IN HERE RUNS ALWAYS FIRST.
          z = Asterisk(1,2); // 1 and 2 is lo and hi range values ;)
            // Z has a value of 3 now because Asterisk(1,2) returns 1 + 2
        }
```

See how this works?
 Now this works because you use the static definition (meaning there must not be an instance of MyMethod  created first to use the method. It's not wrong, but if you can make a program do things with class instances, you better do it that way.

You make an instance of a class, this is called an object, using a special method. This method has the exact name of the Class and constructs an instance of it.
You should study now about constructors, abstract classes etc etc.

I can't say you do it wrong or right either. It is about what the program is all about and you should study the scope for variables and methods, and the encapsulation concept of Object Oriented Programming.
Using only static methods, goes against encapsulation principle, it is possibly wrong but I can't tell for sure.

I hope this helped you and gave you a good direction to go on with your study.

PS: 
To return multiple results, you should return an array of variables, not just a variable.
You can also return nothing and just have it do the job to a needed array. This FORCES you though to make this array public. (Not a good practice)

Finally if multiple value returns are needed to just print them on the console... well, just do it in the method, no need to return anything really.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up not returning anything at all, I think objects are my next step on my programming adventure, so thanks (again) for your comment :)

Comment: yts reply to your deleted "Way too much info and I don't answer his question"  (Why you deleted that?

"am I writing it correctly?"

This part of the original question is what I struggle to guide the guy to understand. Sometimes, much information is better than guiding a guy how to do something the easy-wrong way, don't you think? Your reply might be accpeted, but it will guide him not care about scope and use always static in methods. This leads to spaghetti code. Returning nothing is not wrong, but sometimes it is.

Comment: It's not the wrong way, it's the way that's acceptable at this point in his/her learning. Too much information is confusing. 
(about the deletion..it was a bit harsh, so I took it away before I saw you responded)

Comment: I mentioned that i can't say something is right or wrong. But looking at his question, he/she said that it's the first attempt trying to do this right. Questioning at the same question if his/her code is right or wrong also has to give sometthing more that a mistake in code. That said, I never said you were not right, but such a small amount of information is not confusing for the person, don't undermine him/her. ;)
Still good job giving a good reply. I just explain you why so big answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

mmmmm...you can return types, and (int lowestRange, int highestRange) its not a type. Look at the method definition

```
public static int Asterisk(int lowestRange, int highestRange)
```

the return type is declared as int, so you should return an int value. You can do something like

```
return lowestRange;
return 1;
```

with that in consideration, the error should dissapear. The question is, why do you need to return a value? From what i've read, your methods are supose to print stuff, not to return stuff...

Comment: well...besides, the return statements are outside the metod definition, that wont work...

Comment: When I remove the word "return" I get an error saying "error: missing return statement" so I assumed I had to have one, is there a specific way not to return anything?

EDIT: For some reason the error only shows for MethodOne and not MethodTwo when I remove the return statement, any thoughts?

Comment: yep, the return statement should be inside the method, thats why the compiler claims that is missing...

Comment: Wasn't the idea that I didn't need a return statement at all? I changed the method to be "public static void" instead of just "public static" and this sorted everything out, if you have anything else to add I'd love to hear it though!

Comment: i know, i told you that in this particular case you should not return a value. The idea its that you learn why this happens, so i gave you the answer.

Answer (score -2):

The return statements are out of the method. You have to put them before the close method brackets.

```
public class MyClass{
    public int sum (int a, int b){
         return a + b;
    } // The return have to be before this brackets
}
```